# How to export members from a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups, export

How do I export addresses of members of a Google Groups group that **I am a member** of?

The manager **did not** limit the possibility of viewing the list of members, And I can see the list at:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!members/GROUPNAME
```

but there was no possibility of exporting!

This is how it looks.
Only when you click on the broken address,
This shows the address in full.

[image]

**Is there any way to export the list anyway?**

Comment: Welcome to webapps. An easy way would be to view the page source and extract them from there. On the other hand you could use one of the many online available _"Email extractors"_ for free. Please let us know if you find the suggestions useful  so I can write a proper answer about it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Through the page source I've tried already, but it was not possible.
I'd love to hear about other ways.
Thanks!

Comment: _"... it was not possible"_. May I ask why? Could you save and share a text copy of the source? Can you get any results from the _"Email extractors"_?

Comment: The address is displayed only after the member's name is clicked.
Therefore, only the addresses of friends who click on them will be saved in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshots and use an OCR application to extract the text.

For example: use a screenshot tool like Greenshot or SnagIt or the Windows Snipping Tool.

Save images of the user list, preferably in a lossless format like BMP.
Use an OCR-capable tool such as Acrobat (not Reader) to grab the text out of the images (make pdf, Scan & OCR, Recognize Text)

Copy the text into the application of your choice (e.g. Excel) via the clipboard.
Manually correct OCR errors in the list.

Answer (score -1):

The Google Groups' members email export feature is only available for group owners and administrators not for members.

I never tried to use web-scrapping techniques to get email form a Google Group members page but Google recently announced that they changed Google Groups settings in order to improve the privacy and security of them. Considering this I think that it will be harder than before for regular members to get the email addresses of the other members of the group.

The easier solution is to ask the group owner/administrator to export the email address for you.

Comment: Thank you.
I know this feature is only available for group owners and administrators.

But I'm looking for an idea how to export anyway...